# How to create cblite2 file with python script

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite

I was trying to use `couchbase` in one of my android applications. This app will have static data that are **scraped** from the web. So I want to generate a `cblite2` file with my python script and insert those data and then use this `cblite2` file in android. I can load data from an existing file [according to this](https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/2.7/java-android.html#loading-a-pre-built-database). But how can I generate my initial `cblite2` file?

Comment: I guess you mean ‘scraped’ - extracted from HTML web pages - rather than ‘scrapped - thrown away, discarded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`cblite` command line tool](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-mobile-tools/blob/master/README.cblite.md) to create the database. There are a couple of ways to do the import. I'll describe what seems to me like the simplest way.

Have your script save the JSON documents to a directory. For this example, let's call the diretory `json-documents`. Use the desired document ID as the base name, and `.json` as the extension. For example, if you want a document's ID to be "foo", the filename would be `foo.json`.

Then use the [`cblite cp`](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-mobile-tools/blob/master/Documentation.md#cp-aka-export-import-push-pull) command to import the documents into a new database:

```
cblite cp json-documents/ myNewDatabase.cblite2
```

You can use the other `cblite` subcommands to verify the import was successful.

List the document IDs:

```
cblite ls myNewDatabase.cblite2
```

Display the contents of a document:

```
cblite cat myNewDatabase.cblite2 someDocumentId
```

Comment: To invoke `cblite` from Python, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command-from-python